# Complexity of unrolled loop in saxpy

Tags: time-complexity, runtime-analysis

I'm trying to calculate the complexity of the saxpy method, which aims to solve the equation $y=\alpha*x+y$, where $x$ and $y$, are vectors and $\alpha$ is a scalar.

There two versions of the algorithm, with loop unrolling and without, the version without (as seeing below), I've manage to find the complexity, been $2n$ for the number of floating point operations and $3n$ for the number of access to the vectors, where $n$ is the length of the vectors.

Non-unrolled version:

```
integer function saxpy(x, alfa, y, z) result (rslt)
    implicit none
    real, dimension(:), intent(in) :: x, y
    real, dimension(:), intent(out) :: z
    real, intent(in) :: alfa
    integer :: i, n
    n = size(x)
    if (size(x)/=size(y) .and. size(x)/=size(z)) then
        rslt = -1
        return
    end if
    do i = 1, n
        z(i) = alfa * x(i) + y(i)
    end do
    rslt = 0
end function saxpy
```

Unrolled by a factor of 4:

```
integer function saxpy4(x, alfa, y, z) result (rslt)
    implicit none
    real, dimension(:), intent(in) :: x, y
    real, dimension(:), intent(out) :: z
    real, intent(in) :: alfa
    integer :: i, n, m
    n = size(x)
    if (size(x)/=size(y).and.size(x)/=size(z)) then
        rslt = -1
        return
    end if
    m = mod(n, 4)
    do i = 1, m
        z(i) = alfa * x(i) + y(i)
    end do
    do i = m + 1, n, 4
        z(i) = alfa * x(i) + y(i)
        z(i + 1) = alfa * x(i + 1) + y(i + 1)
        z(i + 2) = alfa * x(i + 2) + y(i + 2)
        z(i + 3) = alfa * x(i + 3) + y(i + 3)
    end do
    rslt = 0
end function saxpy4
```

If someone could shed a light to the problem, I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asymptotic complexity is always "up to a constant factor".

To say "$f(n)$ is $O(g(n))$", that means that there exists a constant $c$, and there exists a constant $n_0$, such that for all $n > n_0$, $\left| f(n) \right| \le c \left|g(n)\right|$.

All this says is that the constant $c$ *exists*, and says nothing about what kind of magnitude it might have. The saxpy operation *must* access every value of the vectors $x$ and $y$ at least once, so it must be at least $O(n)$. Both the original and unrolled versions are both $O(n)$, so they save the same *complexity*, even if the constants are different for each version.

When we are analysing algorithms and need something more precise than asymptotic complexity, we typically count specific things, like floating point operations or number of memory accesses (measured in words). Again, both of your versions are identical when you use a measure like that. You could measure branch instructions, I suppose, but it's hard to see how that would be helpful; on modern CPUs, correctly predicted branches are essentially free, and for loops, branches are typically incorrectly predicted at *most* once.

Anything more than that, and you're not really doing algorithm analysis, you're benchmarking.

The actual runtime depends on a large number of details, including the instruction set of the CPU (how wide is its vector registers anyway?). Indeed, rather than this:

```
m = mod(n, 4)
do i = 1, m
    z(i) = alfa * x(i) + y(i)
end do
do i = m + 1, n, 4
    z(i) = alfa * x(i) + y(i)
    z(i + 1) = alfa * x(i + 1) + y(i + 1)
    z(i + 2) = alfa * x(i + 2) + y(i + 2)
    z(i + 3) = alfa * x(i + 3) + y(i + 3)
end do
```

you probably want to swap these two loops:

```
! Disclaimer: It's been a while since I last wrote any Fortran.
m = n - mod(n, 4)
do i = 1, m, 4
    z(i) = alfa * x(i) + y(i)
    z(i + 1) = alfa * x(i + 1) + y(i + 1)
    z(i + 2) = alfa * x(i + 2) + y(i + 2)
    z(i + 3) = alfa * x(i + 3) + y(i + 3)
end do
do i = m+1,n
    z(i) = alfa * x(i) + y(i)
end do
```

Why? Because if the compiler decides to SIMD-optimise the loop, the loads and stores will be aligned.

All of these implementation details matter in practice, and it's why I can pretty much guarantee that, assuming you don't have a hand-tuned BLAS for your CPU, the best "wall time" will be obtained by letting a modern compiler do all the hard work:

```
! Disclaimer still applies.
integer function saxpy(x, alfa, y, z) result (rslt)
    implicit none
    real, dimension(:), intent(in) :: x, y
    real, dimension(:), intent(out) :: z
    real, intent(in) :: alfa
    if (size(x)/=size(y) .and. size(x)/=size(z)) then
        rslt = -1
        return
    end if
    z = alfa * x + y
    rsult = 0
end function saxpy
```

That's assuming you really need `rsult`.

(Note: The "real" BLAS saxpy includes index increments for `x` and `y`, which is why it's "needed" instead of just using array expressions, but of course you probably knew that...)

Comment: I was imagining that the unrolled version should be less "complex", because it runs faster. Thank you so much!!